# What a strange thing is: Remix with Ropsten testnet: Gas required exceeds limit

Tags: remix, gas, ropsten

I'm trying to run an example Solidity program - Congress from Etherum.org which I believe it should be right, but I always got "**transact to Congress.addMember errored: Gas required exceeds limit: 300000000.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).** " when I call a function in Remix while it can be called successfully from an ether wallet.
The function I called is **addmember(address targetMember, string memberName):**

```
mapping (address => uint) public memberId;
Member[] public members;
struct Member {
    address member;
    string name;
    uint memberSince;
}
function Congress (
    uint minimumQuorumForProposals,
    uint minutesForDebate,
    int marginOfVotesForMajority
)  payable public {
    changeVotingRules(minimumQuorumForProposals, minutesForDebate, marginOfVotesForMajority);
    // It’s necessary to add an empty first member
    addMember(0, "");
    // and let's add the founder, to save a step later
    addMember(owner, 'founder');
}

function addMember(address targetMember, string memberName) onlyOwner public {
    uint id = memberId[targetMember];
    if (id == 0) {
        memberId[targetMember] = members.length;
        id = members.length++;
    }

    members[id] = Member({member: targetMember, memberSince: now, name: memberName});
    MembershipChanged(targetMember, true);
}
```

More strange thing is if I call `addmember(0x45598A0733111F1Cff340504dE74cbCDC54B101d,"Name1")`, Remix told me this gas error, but if I call `addmember(0x0,"Name1")`, It can be done without any problem.

I use Injected web3 option and Ropsten testnet, and I send 0 ether as value, gas limit from 300000 to 300000000, all don't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: The function is onlyOwner are you sending from the owner account? Ropsten has a 6M gas limit you can't set gas higher than that. Also ir works correctly with "Javascript VM" consuming less than 120k gas.

Comment: I call it from owner account. The gas limit doesn't matter because I tried many different figures, all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, It's my stupid mistake. I forgot to put "" into.